# Scala IO monad: what's the point?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, functional-programming, monads

I watched a video recently on how you could come up with the IO monad, the talk was in scala. I am actually wondering what the point of having functions return IO[A] out of them. The lambda expressions wrapped in the IO object are what the mutations are and at some point higher up the change they have to be observed, I mean executed, so that something happens. Are you not just pushing the problem higher up the tree somewhere else?

The only benefit I can see is that it allows for lazy evaluation, in the sense that if you do not call the unsafePerformIO operation no side effects occur. Also I guess other parts of the program could use / share code and deciede when it wants the side effects to occur.

I was wondering if this is all? Is there any advantages in testability? I am assuming not as you would have to observe the effects which sort of negates this. If you used traits / interfaces you can control the dependencies but not when the effects take place on these dependencies.

I put together the following example in code.

```
case class IO[+A](val ra: () => A){
  def unsafePerformIO() : A = ra();
  def map[B](f: A => B) : IO[B] = IO[B]( () => f(unsafePerformIO()))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => IO[B]) : IO[B] = {
    IO( () =>  f(ra()).unsafePerformIO())
  }
}



case class Person(age: Int, name: String)

object Runner {

  def getOlderPerson(p1: Person,p2:Person) : Person = 
    if(p1.age > p2.age) 
        p1
      else
        p2

  def printOlder(p1: Person, p2: Person): IO[Unit] = {
    IO( () => println(getOlderPerson(p1,p2)) ).map( x => println("Next") )
  }

  def printPerson(p:Person) = IO(() => {
    println(p)
    p
  })

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val result = printPerson(Person(31,"Blair")).flatMap(a => printPerson(Person(23,"Tom"))
                                   .flatMap(b => printOlder(a,b)))

   result.unsafePerformIO()
  }

}
```

You can see how the effects are deferred until main which I guess is cool. I came up with this after getting a feel for this from the video.

Is my implementation correct and Is my understanding correct.

I am also wondering whether to get milage it should be combined with the ValidationMonad, as in ValidationMonad[IO[Person]] so we can short circuit when exceptions occurs? Thoughts please.

Blair

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is valuable for the type signature of a function to record whether or not it has side effects. Your implementation of IO has value because it does accomplish that much. It makes your code better documented; and if you refactor your code to separate, as much as possible, logic which involves IO from logic that doesn't, you've made the non-IO-involving functions more composable and more testable. You could do that same refactoring without an explicit IO type; but using an explicit type means the compiler can help you do the separation.

But that's only the beginning. In the code in your question, IO actions are encoded as lambdas, and therefore are opaque; there is nothing you can do with an IO action except run it, and its effect when run is hardcoded.

That is not the only possible way to implement the IO monad.

For example, I might make my IO actions case classes that extend a common trait. Then I can, for example, write a test that runs a function and sees whether it returns the right *kind* of IO action.

In those case classes representing different kinds of IO actions, I might not include hard coded implementations of what the actions do when I run. Instead, I could decouple that using the typeclass pattern. That would allow swapping in different implementations of what the IO actions do. For example, I might have one set of implementations that talk to a production database, and another set that talks to a mock in-memory database for testing purposes.

There is a good treatment of these issues in Chapter 13 ("External Effects and I/O") of Bjarnason & Chiusano's book *Functional Programming in Scala*. See especially 13.2.2, “Benefits and drawbacks of the simple IO type”.

UPDATE: re "swap in different implementations of what the IO actions do", you might look up "free monad", which is one way to arrange for that. Also relevant is "tagless final" style, in which you write monadic code independently of a concrete type such as `IO`.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer I will take a look at those ideas tonight.

Comment: Have you got a code snippet with the sub classes and type classes in mind?

Comment: See Runar's slides that Drexin links to, specifically the `ConsoleIO` stuff. It demonstrates the separation of the declaration of what IO actions exist (`case object GetLine ...`, `case class PutLine ...`) from the definition of what might happen if you ran those actions (`implicit object ConsoleEffect ...`). But note there's other stuff in there too; it isn't minimal code that demonstrates _only_ what I said.

Answer (score 20):

The benefit of using the IO monad is having pure programs. You do not push the side-effects higher up the chain, but eliminate them. If you have an impure function like the following:

```
def greet {
  println("What is your name?")
  val name = readLine
  println(s"Hello, $name!")
}
```

You can remove the side-effect by rewriting it to:

```
def greet: IO[Unit] = for {
  _ <- putStrLn("What is your name?")
  name <- readLn
  _ <- putStrLn(s"Hello, $name!")
} yield ()
```

The second function is referentially transparent.

A very good explanation why using the IO monads leads to pure programs can be found [in Rúnar Bjarnason's slides](http://blog.higher-order.com/assets/scalaio.pdf) from scala.io (video can be found [here](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/io-functional-side-effects)).

Comment: Non-FP programmer here. Why is the second referrentially transparent? The print will depend on user input which is contained inside greet function, no?

Comment: @nawfal It is referentially transparent because it has no effect on the outside world and doesn't depend on outside state.  Every time you run it you get the same thing: an action that when run will print some text and ask for input.  If you wanted to do it twice you could call the function twice to get two identical actions or you could call the function once and reuse the action it returns and your program would be semantically identical.  You could also call it and never use the result which would be semantically identical to never calling the function at all.

Comment: @puhlen I get that, but then when you call that returned action, you have side-effects, right? Basically you are moving side-effectful part to somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. Essentially  the code was moved in  a place where it's side effect is contained. And every time IO[Unit] is returned regardless of what happened within the monad, IO. This is unlike the previous greet method where you might get an IO Exception. Imagine println is writing to disk IO